# Selecting a background style using javascript - how to fix a simple syntax error?

Tags: javascript

I want to just change the background when clicking the button. However, I cannot get the variable `change` to fetch the background of div `test2` and store it as a variable. I know this because `alerting` the value of `test2` shows `undefined`.

I know this seems like a simple fix but I cannot actually find a solution. Is this just a simple syntax error or am I missing something?

An explanation of why this happens would be much appreciated, thanks.

```js
var el = document.getElementById('test');

function changeBG() {
  var change = document.getElementById('test2').background;
  
  el.style.background = change;
}
```

```css
#test {
  background: url('http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2017/08/15/19/434758D400000578-4793442-image-a-5_1502822599189.jpg');
    width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

#test2 {
  background: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/44/Lioness_and_cub.jpg/240px-Lioness_and_cub.jpg');
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>

<button onclick="changeBG();">hi</button>
```

Comment: Because there is no such property as `background` on an HTMLElement

Comment: There is no element test2. Why don't you just add a class?

Comment: so is there no way of storing the background of an element in a variable?

Comment: @user8758206 you can. but you have other problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple reasons for the error/undefined variable. First, there isn't an element with the id 'test2' in your html. You have only assigned css *style* to the id 'test2'. There is only a div with the id 'test'. The other problem is HTML elements do not have the property 'background'. To change the background you would need to use the 'style' property as in `document.getElementById('test2').style.background = "url(...)";`

There are several ways to resolve this, below is one approach using classes.

- Remove the `background` attribute from the div id and create two
  classes, `background` and `background2`.
- In the html, add the `background` to the `test` div as the default
  class (background image).
- Use the `toggle()` method to alternate assignment of the class to the
  div.

Since the original class `background` was already assigned it will be removed and `background2` is added. If you are only trying to change the background *once*, then you can just simply reassign the class (see commented lines).

[toggle](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_class.asp)

[style property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_style.asp)

Note: The reason you can't keep the background attribute as part of the original div's id css and add the class with the new background is because the id takes precedent and will override any class attributes with the same name unless `!important` is added to the end of the class attribute value (`background: url(..) !important;`) though that method should be avoided if possible. Also, The `classList` property is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 if that matters.

```js
var el = document.getElementById('test');

function changeBG() {   
    //to change the background once   
    //el.className = "background2";
    el.classList.toggle('background');
    el.classList.toggle('background2');
}
```

```css
#test {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.background{
    background: url('http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2017/08/15/19/434758D400000578-4793442-image-a-5_1502822599189.jpg');
}

.background2 {
    background: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/44/Lioness_and_cub.jpg/240px-Lioness_and_cub.jpg');
 }
```

```html
<div id="test" class ="background"></div>

<button onclick="changeBG();">hi</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you're looking to do is change style properties, you can simply toggle classes. Its totally unnecessary to create variables to do this unless you're just trying to learn something.

```js
var el = document.getElementById('test');

function changeBG() {
    el.classList.toggle('test1');
    el.classList.toggle('test2');
}
```

```css
#test {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.test1 {
  background: url('http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2017/08/15/19/434758D400000578-4793442-image-a-5_1502822599189.jpg');
}

.test2 {
  background: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/44/Lioness_and_cub.jpg/240px-Lioness_and_cub.jpg');
}
```

```html
<div id="test" class="test1"></div>
<button onclick="changeBG();">change background</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for an old-school solution.

```js
function changeBG() {
var el = document.getElementById('test');
var value = null;
for (let i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++) {
    const mysheet = document.styleSheets[i];
    const myrules = mysheet.cssRules ? mysheet.cssRules : mysheet.rules;
    if(myrules){
      for (let j = 0; j < myrules.length; j++) {
        if (myrules[j].selectorText && 
            myrules[j].selectorText.toLowerCase() === '#test2')     {
          value =  myrules[j].style['background'];
        }
      }
    }
  }
  if(value){
   el.style.background = value;  
  }else{
  alert("test2 not found");
  }
}
```

```css
#test {
  background: url('http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2017/08/15/19/434758D400000578-4793442-image-a-5_1502822599189.jpg');
    width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

#test2 {
  background: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/44/Lioness_and_cub.jpg/240px-Lioness_and_cub.jpg');
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<h4> if you are looking for an old-school solution</h4>

<div id="test"></div>
<button onclick="javascript:changeBG();">hi</button>
<div id="test2"></div>
```